# Wordcloud from Numpy Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science, word-cloud

I'm having trouble generating a wordcloud using numpy array where Column 1 = terms and Column 2 = frequency.

Given the documentation on wordcloud available here: [Wordcloud Documentation](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud)
to use .generate_from_frequencies you need a dictionary.

I've attempted to do this in the code below, however it results in:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'numpy.string_' and
>   'float'

Does anyone know how I can overcome this? I have been stuck on this for hours now and pulling my hair out haha.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

# Create array with all documents classifed as "0" cluster from best performing Kmeans

Cluster_1 = np.empty((0,4613))
Cluster_1_FW = terms

for n in range (0,737): 
    if Euclidean_best[n] == 0:
        Cluster_1 = np.vstack([Cluster_1,X[n,:]])

# Sum frequencies of all words in cluster
Cluster_1_f = np.sum(Cluster_1,axis=0)

print(Cluster_1_f.shape)

Cluster_1_FW = np.vstack([Cluster_1_FW,Cluster_1_f])
Cluster_1_FW = np.transpose(Cluster_1_FW)

d = {}
for a, q in Cluster_1_FW:
    d[a] = q



print(Cluster_1_FW.dtype)

print(np.max(Cluster_1_f))
print(Cluster_1_FW.shape)
print(Cluster_1_FW[0:5,:])
# Create word cloud from word-frequency table stored in Cluster_1_FW
wcCluster1 = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,background_color='white', width=1200,
                          height=1000).generate_from_frequencies(d)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wcCluster1)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, i'm so happy, simply had to change the code below as second part was making it into a string rather than a float:

```
d = {}
for a, q in Cluster_1_FW:
    d[a] = float(q)
```